# Deduce parameter pack w/out passing it explicitly as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, c++11, variadic-templates

Forgive any ignorance of C++ type deduction in this, but I'd like to be able to carry around the parameter pack's definition, so that later I could test for an inner type.  Is this possible?  Something like:

```
template <typename... Args> struct Entity {

    struct Inner {
        typedef Args... entity_args_t;
    };

    struct SomeOtherInner {
        typedef Args... entity_args_t;
    };
};

struct ThingA : Entity<int, string> {
};

struct ThingB : Entity<string, string> {
};

//Want to accept variations of Entity<...>::Inner,
//not Entity<...>::SomeOtherInner
template<typename I>
struct is_Entity_Inner {
    static const bool value
        = is_same<
            typename Entity<typename I::entity_args_t...>::Inner
            , I
        >::value
    ;
};
```

Oui?  Non?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define:

```
template<typename ...> struct types;
```

Then:

```
template <typename... Args> struct Entity {

    struct Inner {
        typedef types<Args...> entity_args_t;
    };

    struct SomeOtherInner {
        typedef types<Args...> entity_args_t;
    };
};
```

Then you can pass `entity_args_t` to a template that has a partial specialization for `types<T...>`. If you typedef the `Entity`, you can instead write a partial specialization for `Entity<T...>`, which may make more sense for your case

```
template <typename... Args> struct Entity {

    struct Inner {
        // Equivalent: typedef Entity entity_args_t;
        typedef Entity<Args...> entity_args_t;
    };

    struct SomeOtherInner {
        typedef Entity<Args...> entity_args_t;
    };
};
```

So having a typedef for `entity_args_t` equal `Entity<Args...>`, you could write this as follows (untested, but should work):

```
template<typename ProbablyInner, typename ProbablyEntity>
struct is_inner_impl : std::false_type 
{ };

template<typename ProbablyInner, typename ...Args>
struct is_inner_impl<ProbablyInner, Entity<Args...>> 
  : std::is_same<
      typename Entity<Args...>::Inner
      ProbablyInner>
{ };

template<typename ProbablyInner, typename = std::true_type>
struct is_inner : std::false_type 
{ };

template<typename ProbablyInner>
struct is_inner<ProbablyInner, 
  std::integral_constant<bool, is_inner_impl<
    ProbablyInner, 
    typename ProbablyInner::entity_args_t>::value>>
  : std::true_type 
{ };
```

Comment: So, in the `is_Entity_Inner` metafunction, I would instead have `is_same<typename I::entity_args_t::template Inner, I>::value`?

Comment: @pheedbaq the critical point is where you access `::entity_args_t`. If you want `is_inner` yield `false` for arbitrary other types, you have to access the type in an SFINAE context, so that if there is no member called `::entity_args_t`, that there is no hard compile time error.

Comment: @litb Not entirely sure I grasp your last comment.  Is that what `typename = void` is accomplishing as the second parameter of `is_inner`?  If a `::entity_args_t` member exists, then the compiler matches it to the specialization.  If not, even though the member doesn't exist, it matches it with `typename = void` version?

Comment: @pheedbaq i subsequently changed my code to not use `enable_if`. I think it bloats the code. If `::entity_args_t` exists, then it can consider the specialization and whether it matches the arguments (the arguments are `<whatever is passed, void>`). `enable_if` as used will always yield `void` in the success-case (if a member exists). In the non-success case (which is when `is_inner_impl<>::value` evaluates to `false`), there exist no `::type` member, and so a SFINAE error occurs. Roughly similar things go on with my `integral_constant<>` version now.

Comment: Ok.  I think I got it.  Much appreciated!